# How to combine multiple lines in CSV into one line

Tags: python, csv

I've been given a large CSV file of which I need to strip down for use in machine learning. I've managed to find a way of splitting the file down into the 2 rows that I require - but I have a problem.

I basically have a file structure like this.

```
 "David", "Red"
 "David", "Ford"
 "David", "Blue"
 "David", "Aspergers"
 "Steve", "Red"
 "Steve", "Vauxhall"
```

And I require the data to look more like this...

```
"David, "Red", "Ford", "Blue", "Aspergers"
"Steve", "Red", "Vaxhaull"
```

I currently have this to strip the CSV files

```
import csv

cr = csv.reader(open("traits.csv","rb"), delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
cr.next() #skipping header line, no point in removing it as I need to standardise data manipuation.


# Print out the id of species and trait values
print 'Stripping input'
vals = [(row[1], row[4]) for row in cr]
print str(vals) + '\n'

with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(vals)
    print 'Sucessfully written to file output.csv'


#for row in cr:
#print row
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a dictionary to store the names as the key and other attributes in a list as value :

```
my_dict={}
with open("traits.csv","rb") as f:
   cr = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
   for row in cr:
       my_dict.setdefault(row[0].strip('" '),[]).append(row[1].strip('" '))
```

result :

```
print my_dict
{'Steve': ['Red', 'Vauxhall'], 'David': ['Red', 'Ford', 'Blue', 'Aspergers']}
```

And for write in new file :

```
with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
    for i,j in my_dict.iteritems():
        writer.writerow([i]+j)
```

> **setdefault(key[, default])**
>
> If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with a value of default and return default. default defaults to None.

Comment: I'm currently getting an output of.

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'setdefault`

Comment: @KeironO Maybe you have a list with name `d` (and defined it after `d={}`) i change its name! try the edited answer!

Comment: I'm still confused as to how I can integrate this into my own program. It seems to work, but doesn't print out the 4th row? (just the 1st)

Comment: @KeironO Sorry i don't get what you mean by 4th row! if you want to write it in a new csv file just loop over the dict items and writer them.

Comment: I don't think my question was sufficient, I'm really sorry about that.

The original text file looks something like...

`"David", "Orange", "Purple", "Red"`

I need to ignore 2 and 3, whilst also doing what I said above in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Use `defaultdict`, it's exactly what you need, here's a sample :

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> md = defaultdict(list)
>>> md[1].append('a')
>>> md[1].append('b')
>>> md[2].append('c')
>>> md[1]
['a', 'b']
>>> md[2]
['c']
```

(Instead of list you may want to use set, in which case you'd call .add instead of .append.)

You can use `iteritems` to access the data easily.